# Saved data disappears from cell phone

Tags: android, android-memory

I have made an app for Android which saves results for skeet shooting. During a session, the user either presses hit or miss. When the session is over, the user press save and the new result is appended to the json-object. After that the result is appended, it is saved to the phone via

```
    public static void saveData(Context context) {
    File path = context.getFilesDir();
    File file = new File(path, "jsonUsr.json");

    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            String objString = usrObject.toString();
            stream.write(objString.getBytes());
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my friend who has my app used it when we were at a competition today. During the session when my app was running and he had started to fill in his result, he receives an sms. He opens the message and reads it. Then instead of reopen my app from the current apps running, he goes to the meny and presses the icon. Suddenly he discovers that all data is gone! Not just the current session, but all results he has entered. I cannot understand that, because there does not even exists in the code a call which deletes the saved json string file.

I have tried to imitate what he did on my phone, but it works perfectly. He has had a lot of problems with the memory with his phone. For a couple of days ago, it complained about that there were not enough memory for upgrading, so he moved things to the SD-card? Is it possible that the data has either been removed due to lack of memory or that it is moved to the SD card?

It is not so much to work with, but I do not have more. Since I cannot recreate it myself, it is hard to know exactly what has happened.

Comment: Any reason you haven't used database?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to always write to a new file in the same directory. If that write succeeds, move the new file onto the config file by changing its name. (this change is atomic)

That way, you will always end up with a valid file, even if the call to write fails for some reason (out of disk, toString() fails, etc.).